# How to convert inner class to regular class in model transformation

Tags: transformation, enterprise-architect, mda

is there any posibility to convert inner class to a regular class while doing transformation?

Class should be in the same package as the wrapper class.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. 
Replace following code:

```
    Class
{
...
%list="InnerClass" @separator="\n" @indent="  "%
}
```

To:

```
    Class
{
...
}
%list="InnerClass" @separator="\n" @indent="  "%
```

This do the trick